# onCLick() problem

Tags: javascript

I have been reading to stay away from JavaScript for a lot of things, however I was messing around with it and it doesnt seem to work (unless I am blind and have missed something)

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="text/javascript">
    function testResults() {
        System.out.println("Got into function");
}
</SCRIPT>
```

And this is my body:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="button" value="Save" name="saveType" style="margin:10px;" onClick="testResults()"/>
</form>
```

From what I have seen of javascipt this should be fine...
Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you have mistaken Java for JavaScript... as far as I know, `System.out.println()` exists in Java, but not in JavaScript.

Comment: System.out.println()? java?, this is JAVASCRIPT!!!! 300 parody ;) anyways. try `alert('got into function')` instead

Comment: @user291652 - You should not bash languages going simply by "what you have read".  There is a lot of ignorance and obsolete data on the web.  Pick up a good book and learn the how's and why's of the js lang.

Comment: onClick="testResults():return false;" to stop it from submitting the form as the event bubbles. Also its a fix for an IE6 bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get it work use this instead:

[Look here - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/673Wp/)

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="button" value="Save" name="saveType" style="margin:10px;" onClick="testResults()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testResults() {
        alert("Got into function");
}
</script>
```

it is `type="text/javascript` and not `language="text/language"` also in javascript you have to use `alert()`.

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for not just jumping to be patronising without understanding the circumstances for the coder....

Answer (score 8):

Use `console.log` instead of `system.out.println`...

Javascript is not Java!

Comment: `console.log` usually requires that the Browser has a debugger installed.

Comment: I hardly consider IE as a browser :)

Comment: @RoToRa if you are debugging JavaScript problems, then you should probably be using a browser that supports a debugger.  Exception is when it's a browser specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

- it's `type="text/javascript"`
- why capital letters?
- `System.out.println` is Java

Stay away from JavaScript? Currently it's almost like the opposite, but as almost always it depends on what you have to do :)

Answer (score 0):

- Java => `System.out.println` or `System.out.print`
- Javascript => `console.log`

:)

Comment: I would actually think that the Javascript analog to `System.out.print` would be `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a standard output like that. You have a few options:

- If you have a debugging console running, you can use `console.log("log a message")`
- You can output debug information to a HTML element: `document.getElementById("myelement").innerHTML = "message here";`

There are loads more options - I'd suggest learning Javascript properly. It's not that much like Java.